# io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Network is unreachable:

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have created a minecraft server which perfectly allows me and people using my wifi router to join (using localhost or the ip), but when anyone using a different wi fi router attempt to join, they get this message:

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Network is unreachable:

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You have an [internal and an external IP](https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/whats-the-difference-between-external-and-local-ip-addresses). Anyone connecting from somewhere outside of your network needs to use the external IP. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: I have been using freedns to change the ip of my server (still linked with the external ip). Could this be the reason my server is not connecting